# A function to set a value to a "label"

Tags: c++, function

So I am wanting to write a function that will set value to itself. Here's a example of the function "in action".

```
 setToValue(height, 62.7);

 setToValue(weight, 155);
```

If I knew where to start, I wouldn't be posting here. But here's what I got. I thought it would be easy to get an answer here, guess not.

```
double setToValue(string label,double value)
  {
    label = "value";
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: What !!!!  Explain it with more details. What do you mean by set value to itself ( did you mean return value ? ).

Comment: That's about as far as I know how? Basically all i want is to set a variable height to the value in the second argument,. @ArunA.S

Comment: pass the first parameter by reference and the second by value, and set the first to the second inside the function

Comment: got an example there @samgak

Comment: void setToValue(double& label,double value){label = value;}

Comment: Thank you Sam, if you add it as an answer I will accept it. @samgak

Comment: I think your frustration with the site, and the site's with this question, is because this is really, *really* basic. For example, searching for `c++ function` on google, I got [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/) and under `Arguments passed by value and by reference` you have >
When a variable is passed by reference, what is passed is no longer a copy, but the variable itself...

Comment: @Sharadh This community is more toxic than any other community I've been in. That's besides the point. I did as much research as I could withstand at 1 AM. I wanted a easy answer. I got it. :)

Comment: My own experience is quite different: it's the most intelligent and thoughtful community *when* I'm on the intelligent and thoughtful questions. :)
I understand your state, and the honesty. That said, when you want an easy answer do expect the question not to get downvoted. People just want to avoid questions that can be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that easily by passing label as reference ( I'm expecting `label` to be a double and not a string ) . Here is how

```
void setToValue(double &label , double value )
  {
    label = value;
  }
```

Note that you don't need to make the function as type double as it is not returning anything useful ( it would just be a waste ).

Or, you could do it like this

```
void setToValue(string &label,string value)
  {
    label = value;
  }

  int main()
   {
    string label;
    setToValue(label,"25.25");
    cout<<label;    
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the first parameter by reference and the second by value, and set the first to the second inside the function e.g:

```
void setToValue(double& label,double value)
{
     label = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to cast the double to a char array (or a string)?

use sprintf:

```
sprintf(height,"%f",0.344);
```

Done!